# How to use mat-icon with ShadowDom

Tags: angular, angular-material, shadow-dom

In my Angular project, I have a component with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` and I need to use some of the [mat-icon](https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline) inside of it.

So in the component's SCSS file, I do this import: `@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons")`, but for example, if I try to use this icon: `<i class="material-icons">face</i>` I just see the word 'face' and not the icon.
Of course, it works if I remove `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`

Comment: Can't you keep the import global? So instead of importing it in the component scss, import it in the global stylesheet?

Comment: How can I import it globally if the encapsulation of the component is shadowDom?

Comment: AFAIK global stylesheets are available to every component. The only difference is, is that your component stylesheet is applying it styles globally `ViewEncapsulation.None`, shadow `ShadowDom` or scoped `Emulated`.

Comment: [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)

Comment: sorry but if make import in index.html or in angular.json I can't see anything anyway

Comment: Instead of import, you can create the whole SVG icon **inside** a component, bit more work upfront, but way more flexible (and smaller in size). See my pet-project https://iconmeister.github.io

Comment: @user14649759 Have you imported the module?

Comment: @Silvermind yes, instead if I remove viewEncapsulation it works